# Jump to another message via a button and assign another role at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I have created a button that lets a user jump to another message in another text channel.

The user has `Role1` as soon as he presses the button he should get the role `Role2` and jump to the textchannel which is only enabled for `Role2`.

Unfortunately this does not work because the following error occurs `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get_role'`

How can I make a user jump to another message and give him a new role?

```py
class Google(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, interaction):
        super().__init__()
        # we need to quote the query string to make a valid url. Discord will raise an error if it isn't valid.
        url = f'https://discord.com/channels/<id>'

        # Link buttons cannot be made with the decorator
        # Therefore we have to manually create one.
        # We add the quoted url to the button, and add the button to the view.
        role = interaction.guild.get_role(<id>)
        interaction.user.add_roles(role)
        self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label='Click Here', url=url))

@bot.command()
async def google(ctx: commands.Context,):
    """Returns a google link for a query"""
    await ctx.send(f'Google Result for', view=Google(discord.Interaction))
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 178, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Implementierung\My_first_app\discord\main.py", line 246, in google
    await ctx.send(f'Google Result for', view=Google(discord.Interaction))
  File "D:\Implementierung\My_first_app\discord\main.py", line 239, in __init__
    role = interaction.guild.get_role(<id>)
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get_role'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 950, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 187, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'get_role'
```

Comment: either try doing `interaction.guild().get_role()` or first `g = interaction.guild` then `g.get_role()`.

Comment: @3nws thanks for the hint. Bot both code snippets don't work. I got the following error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'property' object is not callable`. For `role = interaction.guild().get_role()`

Comment: I just noticed that you are passing a class not an instance. Your command is also not a slash command but a text command. Revise it to be a slash command and pass the interaction that invokes the command to the view. Not the `discord.Interaction` class.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Could you please provide a code snippet for understanding it better? :/

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you are passing a class object to your view not an interaction object. And since `add_roles` is a coroutine you can't `await` it in `__init__` so you better do it in the command itself instead. Hence, your view doesn't even need the interaction object.

```py
class Google(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # we need to quote the query string to make a valid url. Discord will raise an error if it isn't valid.
        url = f"https://discord.com/channels/<id>"

        # Link buttons cannot be made with the decorator
        # Therefore we have to manually create one.
        # We add the quoted url to the button, and add the button to the view.
        self.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="Click Here", url=url))


@bot.tree.command(name="google", guild=None)
async def google(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    """Returns a google link for a query"""
    role = interaction.guild.get_role(<id>)
    await interaction.user.add_roles(role)
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        f"Google Result for", view=Google() # If for some reason you need the interaction in your view you can pass it as an argument.
    )
```

As for how to make it a slash command instead of a text command, you need to set it as a command in the bot's command tree (`bot.tree.command()`).

To register your slash command to discord you need owner only a sync command. Mine is like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(
    ctx: commands.Context[Bot],
    guilds: commands.Greedy[discord.Object],
    spec: Optional[Literal["~"]],
) -> None:
    if not guilds:
        if spec == "~":
            fmt: List[AppCommand] = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        else:
            fmt: List[AppCommand] = await ctx.bot.tree.sync()

        await ctx.send(
            f"Synced {len(fmt)} commands {'globally' if spec is None else 'to the current guild.'}"
        )
        return

    fmt_i: int = 0
    for guild in guilds:
        try:
            await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
        else:
            fmt_i += 1

    await ctx.send(f"Synced the tree to {fmt_i}/{len(guilds)} guilds.")
```

Run your code and use the `<prefix>sync` (with no arguments to sync as global) command to sync your slash commands, then you can use it.